# Are the words "Aural" and "Oral" homophones?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, vowels, homophones

Are the words "Aural" and "Oral" usually pronounced the same?  Does it vary by dialect?  Are there strategies that people use to differentiate them when listening to spoken English?

Comment: What does your dictionary say? Does it give the same IPA transcription for both?

Comment: I pronounce them with an A and O respectively, but it would be hard for a third party to clearly distinguish one from the other in a word stream.  Webster's and Oxford give the same pronunciation for both, which I find a bit odd.

Comment: In American English, as given in [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse#page/n5/mode/2up), both are pronounced /'ɔrəl/, and in addition, _oral_ may also be pronounced /'orəl/ -- if, of course, tense and lax vowels are not neutralized before /r/, the way they are in most rhotic American lects.

Comment: I have the cot-caught merger, and use the *cot* vowel for *aural* and the *force* vowel with *oral*. That may be because I learned them from reading rather than hearing, however.

Comment: @HotLicks What vowels exactly do you mean by that? Are you saying you pronounce _aural_ with the same vowel as _father_? Or like _Harold_ without the h and d?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - "Short" A, but not quite as in "father".  More like in "automatic", "Austin", "audible", et al.  "Oral" begins with an "oh where oh where did my little dog go" sound.

Answer (score 5):

> Are the words "Aural" and "Oral" usually pronounced the same?

Yes

> Does it vary by dialect?

Judging by the answers and comments here, they do do. That said, these differences appear to be idiosyncratic rather than by accent. The OED, whose IPA I have used below, suggests that in other accents (AE) the pronunciation of both words is as homonyms

> Are there strategies that people use to differentiate them when listening to spoken English?

Yes. They include context. If you are deaf and go for an aural examination, it is clear what is meant as nobody is going to look in your mouth – likewise the dentist is not going to look in your ear.

I came across the difference in school when aural and oral exams were announced.

Oral was always pronounced oral /ˈɔːrəl/ as this was the commonest type and the default.

Purely to emphasise the difference where context was lacking, aural was occasionally [mis]pronounced owr’l /aʊrəl/ but, in deference to the strange pronunciation, the speaker would often point to their ear.

As far as examinations were concerned, quite early on, the phrase “[aural] comprehension exams” took the place of aural exams – and then the word “aural” was abandoned, and then the oral exam became "the spoken exam".

My accent is East Midlands with influences of Yorkshire moderated with some RP and I can detect no difference between oral and aural when I speak and when I listen to other people - all rhyme with choral /ˈkɔːrəl/ but not coral /ˈkɒrəl/.

Answer (score 4):

*Aural* and *oral* are “supposed” to be pronounced the same in almost all accents of English (the exception would be accents without the “north-force merger”). Most dictionaries do not give distinct pronunciations for these two words. Although it's not unheard of for people to pronounce them differently, distinguishing them by sound usually involves the use of some pronunciation that could be considered a “mispronunciation”.

#### *Aural* has the long *north* vowel as the outcome of the *thought* vowel before /r/

Words spelled with "au" followed by "r" are not that common, so it's a little hard to describe their pronunciations in terms of a general rule. But *aura, dinosaur, Minotaur, centaur, thesaurus, tyrannosaurus* are other words where "aur" is standardly pronounced as the vowel found in *north*.

*Laurel* has a pronunciation with the "short o" vowel in British English, /ˈlɒrəl/, which can be considered irregular. (A few words spelled with *au* before another consonant also have irregular pronunciations with "short o" in British English, such as *sausage* /ˈsɒsɪdʒ/.)

As mentioned in David Robinson’s and Greybeard's answers, *aural* is sometimes pronounced with the *sour* diphthong. The phonetician John Wells made a blog post mentioning the "ˈaʊrəl" pronunciation of *aural,* and the comments below it have some more discussion: ["trauma", *John Wells's Phonetic Blog*](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/09/trauma.html).

Anecdotally, for some American English speakers it is possible to pronounce *aural* with the vowel of *caught* (i.e. pronouncing the first syllable like the word "awe"), contrasting with the vowel in *oral*. See the forum posts here: http://www.verduria.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=73&start=200 as well the comments left beneath your question by Hot Licks and choster. For a speaker who merges *cot* and *caught* as an unrounded vowel, this could be *aural* [ɑrəl] vs. *oral* [orəl], or for a speaker who has the *north-force* merger but no unrounding of the vowel in *caught*, this could be *aural* [ɔrəl] vs. *oral* [orəl].

#### *Oral* has the long *force* vowel as the outcome of the "long o" vowel before /r/

*Oral* is an *-al* adjective, a class of words that come from Latin and that generally are pronounced in a way consistent with the "[traditional English pronunciation of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin) words". In the case of *oral,* the relevant part of the traditional Latin  pronunciation rules is a rule saying that a vowel letter takes its "long" pronunciation when it comes in the second-to-last syllable of a word and is followed by only a single consonant letter. Since the O in "oral" meets both of these criteria, it is regular for it to be pronounced as a "long o" sound, which before a /r/ is normally realized as the *force* vowel.

There are some exceptions to the traditional pronunciation rules: the most relevant one is *moral,* which British English speakers pronounce as /ˈmɒrəl/, with a "short o" sound. (*Coral* also has a "short o" in British English pronunciation, but it is not an *-al* adjective.)

*Oral* doesn't seem to be a well-established exception, but it sounds like a few British English speakers make it /ɒrəl/, rhyming with *moral* and *coral.* Aside from Tony Mountifield's answer, which seems to be saying this, the Teflpedia article "[Pronunciation exercises: /ɒrV/ vs /ɔːrV/](https://teflpedia.com/Pronunciation_exercises:_/%C9%92rV/_vs_/%C9%94%CB%90rV/)" points out that the [Collins Dictionary entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oral) for "oral in British" lists the variant pronunciation /ˈɒrəl/ after /ˈɔːrəl/.

Comment: It's hard to take your Teflpedia article seriously when they purport that Americans have the same vowel in all of *thought, cloth, north, force*.  Rather, they're in pairs, with the former pair sharing lax /ɔ/ and the latter pair sharing tense /o/. They even admit they’re lying: **“Many people pronounce /ɔː/ and /ɔːr/ with different vowels (e.g. "sauce" as [sɔs] and "source" as [sors]); however since the difference is predictable *there is no problem using the same symbol* in both cases (e.g. /sɔːs/ and /sɔːrs/).”** That’s idiotic. Different sounds, different symbols, duh.

Comment: @tchrist: They're usually predictable, except some New Yorkers pronounce *aura*, *Laura*, and possibly *aural* with the *sauce* vowel, and *core*, *Lora*, and possibly *oral* with the *source* vowel.

Comment: @tchrist That's not idiotic. That's a reasonable practice, given that Teflpedia is giving *phonemic* pronunciations. Note that it puts them between slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question asks about whether people can tell the difference I am going to answer for myself and my dialect rather than referring to a dictionary.

I speak Standard Southern English English and I pronounce them the same as far as I know. I cannot tell the difference when I hear them whatever accent the speaker has.

There is one exception and that is that I sometimes hear *aural* with the same vowel as *now*. Sometimes it is clear they are deliberately pronouncing it that way to distinguish it but sometimes I am not sure if they know how to pronounce it.

I never hear them pronounced slightly differently.

Comment: @andyt My mistake. I thought it was a recognized term. Research shows it isn't. I mean the standardized version of the language of southern England that is close to what is sometimes called BBC English. *Standard Southern English English* would be clearer so I have edited my answer, but this term is unwieldy and often avoided. The term Standard British English is sometimes used but many find that objectionable as it appears to prioritize southern England over the rest of the country and and the other nations of Britain.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Whether it's clearer or more politically accurate, it is more common in language circles to say  'British English'. 'English English' sounds even more 'little England' than 'British English'.

Comment: Yes, @mitch, I agree I speak a dialect of BE, but the problems are with the adjectives *Standard* and *Southern* put in front of the term. People here in Scotland get offended (quite reasonably) when they hear the term *British* used as the adjective for England which is why I am not going to use it when describing what part of England my accent is from.

Comment: @DavidRobinson You may have a very good case, I'm just pointing out that it is out of the mainstream and that others outside of Scotland might get confused at your usage.

Comment: @mitch Point taken and thank you. It's just the the word *British* is so commonly misused outside these islands. (that I'm bit even going to name!) that I've learnt to avoid it to avoid both confusion and offence.

Comment: From my side of the pond, "Southern English" is the dialect whose speakers address people as "y'all" and in which "bless your heart" is a dig.

Comment: I've come across  the same (also mainly southern England). Pronouncing *aural* as *owral* (no IPA on my mobile) is used rarely, for disambiguation, while the pronunciation of *oral* is fixed. More commonly, an alternative to *aural* would be used, especially in speech. See note at [OxfordDictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aural) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have always lived in Southern England, and am a bit of a language pedant. I don’t know if others would consider it correct, but I always distinguish by pronouncing aural like choral, and oral like coral. I hate it that so many pronounce them both like choral. And pronouncing aural like “owral” makes it sound like a German word.

Comment: I find this answer to be very interesting in a slightly bewildering fashion because as far as I know, "choral" and "coral" are exact homophones; so I am very curious as to what distinction you actually make between the "-oral" parts.

Comment: @Hellion _Choral_ (being derived from _chorus_) has a long vowel, /ˡkɔːrəl/, while _coral_ has a short vowel, /ˡkɔrəl ~ kɒrəl/. Well, in theory at least. Even in BrE, many people pronounce them the same (like _aural_ and _oral_). The distinction between /ɒ/ and /ɔː/ is disappearing before /r/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Is the distinction as a whole really disappearing? I hadn't heard of that: although I had heard that certain words with ambiguous spellings, like *florist,* may show variation, I thought that words like *horrid, horrible, sorry, sorrel, borrow, sorrow, torrent* were firmly /ɒ/-only words in British English, and words like *story, gory, glory, adorable* were firmly /ɔː/-only words.

Comment: @sumelic I think the distinction is on its way out, at least among many younger speakers. An at least partial merger of the two, with non-distinctive vacillation in vowel length and often a complete merger of vowel quality, seems anecdotally to be very common in younger speakers; less so in older speakers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Oh, which direction is the neutralized quality? Would speakers with an indistinct or merged quality use a vowel in *sorrow, sorry, horrible* that is more [o]-like than the vowel in *lot,* or a vowel in *g**o**ry, glory, ad**o**rable* that is more [ɔ~ɒ]-like than the vowel in *g**ore*** or *ad**ore*** (which I understand to be pronounced as [oː] by many southern British speakers)?

Comment: @sumelic The latter, I’d say; it’s closer to the archetypal _sorry_ vowel than to the _gory_ vowel.

Comment: @Hellion Though I lack the *cot–caught* merger myself, I still use tense (“long”) vowels like /o/ and /e/ and /i/ before every /r/. The lax ones sound funny to me—if I even notice. I bet you, too, have the extremely common tense–lax neutralization of vowel phonemes before /r/ that John Lawler mentioned. My own instinct is to  both generate and perceive nothing but tense monophthongs there, which means I hear whatever is said as tense there even when it isn't. I *can* overcome this with deliberate attention (eg, *merry–Mary*), but it takes concentration and quickly evaporates once out of mind.

Comment: @Hellion I’m surprised to hear of *choral* and *coral* being considered homophones. I pronounce the “o” in *choral* the same as in *for*, and in *coral* the same as in *hot*.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say that in America they’d most likely be pronounced the same, whereas in England the difference is more readily apparent to the person hearing this. Certainly, as one from Southern England I’d say this is true, as I believe some understanding is lost when not making clear the difference. I feel it (pronouncing them the same) is effectively bastardizing the language.

Comment: It would help if you actually told us what the difference between them is for you. British dictionaries say they're [pronounced](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oral) the [same.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aural)